# Reset Windows 2008 Server Permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008

I changed the admin user name on a 2008 64-bit Enterprise server, and I want to reset the permissions which will hopefully resolve an issue I'm having.

I want to do something similar to what is in this blog post using subinacl.msi, however geared towards 2008.

http://www.kemalkaradag.com/post/2010/06/21/Windows-Update-Error-Code-80070490.aspx

What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually experiencing problems?  Security permissions in Windows are based on the account's SID (System ID.)  The built-in local Admin's account always ends in "-500".  The SID does not change when you rename the account, thus renaming the account should have no effect on security permissions.

Could you explain the actual issue that you're experiencing?  I'm concerned that you may be chasing a false lead.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I'm getting error code: 80070490 when trying to install two Windows updates:

KB967723
KB981793

The problem seemed to arise when I renamed the administrator account on the server.

Windows gave the suggestion to stop the update service, then clear the update history and downloads, then start the service again. Tried that, but it didn't help.

If you have any ideas, let me know. I was just going off that guys blog post since it seemed to be a similar scenario with the same error code.

Thanks

Comment: Check this out: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverManagement/thread/bf5a7c23-dfb4-4d1a-8b8c-80efcdbd6f6f

-Waldo

Answer (score 0):

Not that I understand why changing the name would give you any troubles, nor why you'd want to reset the permissions - but you can use secedit to [restore the setup default policy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313222) if you really want:

```
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose
```